# What is the difference between "asymptotically optimal" algorithm and "close to optimal" in Algorithm Analysis?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

As far as I understand, an algorithm with an upper bound on its running time given by $t(n)$ and a lower bound given by $b(n)$ is said to be "asymptotically optimal" iff

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{t(n)}{b(n)} < \infty$$

In this sense, an algorithm such that $t(n) = 2^{2h-1}$ and $b(n) = 2^{h-1}$ *is not* asymptotically optimal, as the limit above is infinite. However, I have found several times in the literature [1,2] that an algorithm with those bounds *is* "close to optimal".

Here it comes my question:
What is the difference between the notions of "asymptotically optimal" and "close to optimal"?

*[1] J. Esparza, P. Ganty, S. Kiefer, and M. Luttenberger. Parikh’s theorem: A simple and direct automaton construction. IPL, pages 614–619, 2011.*

*[2] G. Pighizzini. Deterministic pushdown automata and unary languages. Interna- tional Journal of Foundations of Computer Science, 20(04):629–645, 2009.*

Comment: The way I read it, at least in the paper by Esparza *et al.*, is that their construction is much closer to the lower bound ($O(4^n)$ vs. $O(2^n)$) than other constructions. (The $O(n^n)$ cited in the introduction.)